# How to simulate ESME send SMS to a mobile client

Tags: sms, simulator, smpp

I want to simulate the process of ESME sending an SMS to a Person B. How can I do this? I tried with LogicaOpenSMPP. I can send SMS to SMSC from ESME but i don't know how to forward that message to a another client.
how can i do so? or is there any alternatives?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal using Smscsim. With the use of SMSCSim we can simulate the process of A sending a message to B quite easily.

Comment: You mean SMPPSim from Selenium? If not can you give a link of SMSCSim?

Answer (score 1):

LogicaOpenSMPP doesn't have any forward function as the website stated

> The application behaves as a real SMSC with SMPP interface, your
>   application can bind to it, send messages, unbind etc., however
>   nothing will get delivered anywhere as all the responses are only
>   made-up by the Simulator.

If you really need to do that, download the source and try to inject your forward functions.

Comment: Thanks for you help HenryLok. Is there any alternative ways to simulate that?